# Difference artifacts with makefile when include objects differently

Tags: c++, c, makefile, continuous-integration, ide

I am writing a makefile for a CI-Pipeline to build and deliver embedded artifacts. At first step, I was trying to get the same .bin and .hex files by compiling with a own written makefile and withing a IDE when using the same toolchain and same settings.
I noticed that there was difference outputs.

Yesterday, I was trying to figure out why is that happening.
I figured out that there was some little difference in replacing suffix from source file .c and .cpp to .o file.
I used in my makefile like this OBJ := ${SRCS:.c=.o}.
The makefile of the IDE included every file one by one.

Then I replaced the .o files like the makefile of the IDE and voila, I got the same outputs.

So my question is, what is the difference in using OBJ:=${SRCS:.c=.o with
OBJ := File1.o File2.o etc.?

Comment: The order of the files would be my guess

Comment: You seems to be right. I just changed the order of the files from the makefile which was generated by the IDE. The hexfile is different.
Why the order of the files matters?

Comment: Since you don't explain what you mean by "difference outputs" we can't help you.  That could mean 100 different things.  If you want to know the answer, please edit your question and add in useful details such as the output you see that is different (old versus new).  Please use cut and paste (not screenshots) and format the content as a code block so it's readable.

Comment: Different in hexfile Output after compiling and linking with arm-none-eabig-gcc/g++. 
I can´t put code here because its company related.